# appointment in the Outlook Calendar

Tags: calendar, outlook, exchangewebservices, managed, appointment

I am using VB.Net and EWS Managed API to create appointments in Exchange 2010. When i call the "Save" method, an appointment is not created on the first machine but when i use the same Code on the second machine it works!

Thanks.

I use below code to save an appointment in the Outlook Calendar:

```
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(myKalender)
    appointment.IsReminderSet = False

    Try
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
          Function(se As Object, _
          cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, _
          chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, _
          sslerror As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) True


        appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)

        Console.Write("erfolgreich Eingetragen " & Now)
    Catch
        Console.Write("Fehler beim Erstellen des Termins " & Now & " " & Err.Description)
    End Try
```